# Search in a Json in javascript

Tags: json, search

i am try to find a value in a json. The json can be different structure with one or two deep, some like this:

```
{"name": "John", "address": {"street": "streetOne", "code": "bar1"}, "phone":"2123445"}
```

In the first level it 's easy, but if there are second level I don't know how to search in.

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected value ?

Comment: In this case will be code, but it can be any.